# Xcode: cstdlib no member named "xxx" in the global namespace

Tags: c++, xcode

[image]

I only change the search path to inform Xcode where opencv locates.
Here's my search paths:

```
Framework search path: /usr/local/lib
Library search path: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11/lib
                     /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11_1/lib
                     /user/local/lib
Header search path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
                    /usr/local/include
```

The errors:

```
    In file included from /Users/lilisun/Documents/opencv_projects/faceExtractor/faceExtractor/main.cpp:8:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp:46:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:49:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h:55:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:44:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/tr1/stdlib.h:32:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/tr1/cstdlib:34:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:118:11: error: no member named 'div_t' in the global namespace
  using ::div_t;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:119:11: error: no member named 'ldiv_t' in the global namespace
  using ::ldiv_t;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:121:11: error: no member named 'abort' in the global namespace
  using ::abort;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:122:11: error: no member named 'abs' in the global namespace
  using ::abs;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:123:11: error: no member named 'atexit' in the global namespace
  using ::atexit;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:129:11: error: no member named 'atof' in the global namespace
  using ::atof;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:130:11: error: no member named 'atoi' in the global namespace
  using ::atoi;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:131:11: error: no member named 'atol' in the global namespace
  using ::atol;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:132:11: error: no member named 'bsearch' in the global namespace
  using ::bsearch;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:133:11: error: no member named 'calloc' in the global namespace
  using ::calloc;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:134:11: error: no member named 'div' in the global namespace
  using ::div;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:135:11: error: no member named 'exit' in the global namespace
  using ::exit;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:136:11: error: no member named 'free' in the global namespace
  using ::free;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:137:11: error: no member named 'getenv' in the global namespace
  using ::getenv;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:138:11: error: no member named 'labs' in the global namespace
  using ::labs;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:139:11: error: no member named 'ldiv' in the global namespace
  using ::ldiv;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:140:11: error: no member named 'malloc' in the global namespace
  using ::malloc;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:142:11: error: no member named 'mblen' in the global namespace
  using ::mblen;
        ~~^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.1.0/cstdlib:143:11: error: no member named 'mbstowcs' in the global namespace
  using ::mbstowcs;
        ~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Comment: You should give us a minimal and complete example that reproduce this.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Maybe there's a problem with the project configuration (most likely system header paths)?

Comment: @Hiura sorry for lack of reproducibility. But I really cannot give an example.

Comment: @AlexandreHamez I update the changes I make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find what mistake I made. 
In the Header search path: I use `/usr/local/include` with recursive. 
After I change it to 
`/usr/local/include non-recursive` 
`/usr/local/include/opencv non-recursive` 
`/usr/local/include/opencv2 non-recursive`

It works. But I still don't know why the recursion version would cause errors.

Comment: How to do that? add `-I/usr/local/include non-recursive` to compiler?